# Text cut off when generate pdf file from html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation

I need generate pdf file from html, now I use gem https://github.com/Studiosity/grover
Content is dynamic, but now I see text often cut off on bottom of page. Anyone can help me ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.php), You should make some changes in your views to make them possible to fit in PDF's. It probably something like, converting every paragraph to a container that holds one. And the CSS page-break-inside Property will be helpful for you to not to break crossed over to the content but at the place where block starts or ends.

I think, what is being cutted off is as same as what happens when you try to print the page. This way, you can debug it.